# fuel php ErrorException [ Parsing Error ]: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '

Tags: mysql, fuelphp

Does anyone know why I get a parsing error with the following code?

```
'always_load'  => array(

     array('auth');
     array(
          array('auth'  => PKGPATH.'auth/')
      );

    'packages'  => array(
        'orm',
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A config file is one long nested or multi-dimensional array, so you never use semi-colon's, only comma's. This is standard PHP array notation.